# Pythontex in TeXShop

Tags: texshop, pythontex

I use TeXShop version 4.51 on macOS Catalina version 10.15.7.
Followed the README.pdf titled "The Pythontex engine by Richard Koch"

1. Downloaded anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos
2. Found a pythontex.engine online and put in /Library/TeXShop/Engines

Followed README by Geoffrey Poore and put different pythontex files in texmf sub-folders.

Ran LaTeX on pythotex_gallery.tex.
When I ran Pythontex on the same file, I got the following message
"Can't find required tool.
/Users/stang9/Library/TeXShop/Engines/pythontex.engine does not have the executable bit set."

I could not get Pythontex to work.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the Terminal and type `chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/pythontex.engine`.

Comment: Thank you, Alan.  I typed in the terminal.  When I ran pythontex, the console went blank.  I wonder if I did something wrong.

Comment: Copy/Paste rather than type. It's too easy to make a typing error. Finally, I checked and the pythontex.engine I see seems to ahve the execute bit already set. Did you Copy the file or drag and drop it from ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/pythontex to ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines? You also must edit the .engine file to give the correct PATH to your python distribution; e.g., I have anaconda python3 in ~/opt/anaconda3/bin.

Comment: Thank you, Herb.  I copied the code to the terminal.  I also dragged the pythontex.engine file to the .../Engines folder.  Do you mind giving more instructions on how to alter the code in the pythontex.engine file, assuming my file is not corrupted?

Comment: Where is your python located. Running `which python` in Terminal should give you the answer.

Comment: /Users/stang9/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: Change line 4 of pythontex.engine to `export PATH=~/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` and see if it works. There is another way to do this using one of the `latexmk` based engines and a platexmkrc file but see if this works for you.

Comment: Herb, I appreciate your help.  Unfortunately, it did not work.  I suspect my file is corrupted.  Is there a way to download the right pythontex.engine file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having a problem with the pythontex.engine here is a way to use one of the latexmk based engines. First take your .tex ans associated files and put them in a folder by themselves; this creates a ``project''. Then create a file names `platexmkrc` containing the code, by John Collins, below (select, copy and paste to prevent problems)

```
# Support for pythontex in v. 0.16 or higher, with latexmk 4.62 or higher

$oldPATH = $ENV{"PATH"};
$ENV{"PATH"} = "${HOME}/opt/anaconda3/bin:$oldPATH";

$clean_ext .= " pythontex-files-%R/* pythontex-files-%R";
push @generated_exts, 'pytxcode';

$pythontex = 'pythontex %O %S';
$extra_rule_spec{'pythontex'}  = [ 'internal', '', 'mypythontex', "%Y%R.pytxcode",  "%Ypythontex-files-%R/%R.pytxmcr",    "%R", 1 ];

sub mypythontex {
   my $result_dir = $aux_dir1."pythontex-files-$$Pbase";
   my $ret = Run_subst( $pythontex, 2 );
   rdb_add_generated( glob "$result_dir/*" );
   my $fh = new FileHandle $$Pdest, "r";
   if ($fh) {
      while (<$fh>) {
         if ( /^%PythonTeX dependency:\s+'([^']+)';/ ) {
         print "Found pythontex dependency '$1'\n";
             rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $aux_dir1.$1 );
     }
      }
      undef $fh;
   }
   else {
       warn "mypythontex: I could not read '$$Pdest'\n",
            "  to check dependencies\n";
   }
   return $ret;
}
```

and place that file in the ``project'' folder; this is done to localize the contents of the platexmkrc file to that project. Next, at the top of your .tex file put the line

```
% !TEX program = pdflatexmk
```

which will tell TeXShop to use the `pdflatexmk` engine which will completely typeset your file. Typeset your file in TeXShop using the `Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T)` menu command.

Comment: I created the file pdflatexmk as  .tex and .engine files (since I am not sure which extension is right), and put the code "% !TEX program = pdflatexmk" at the top of the .tex file.  When I choose LaTeX and typeset, the console shows the following message, "Rc files read:
  /Users/stang9/Library/TeXShop/bin/latexmkrcedit
  /Users/stang9/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk/pdflatexmkrc
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020, version: 4.70b.
Latexmk: All targets (1.pdf) are up-to-date" but no pdf file was shown.

Comment: NO NO NO. The file has no extension, it's just called `platexmkrc`. There is no need to do anything with engine files, TeXShop already has everything. Just put the `platexmkrc` file in the same folder as your .tex source file; put the line `% !TEX program = pdflatexmk` at the top of the .tex file and typeset it in TeXShop using the `Typeset->Typeset` menu command (or Cmd-T keyboard shortcut).

Comment: For the pdflatexmk file, do I just copy and paste the code into a new TeXShop file with Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8) and File Format: TeX File?  I am sorry that I lack programming background.

Comment: Yes, and after you save it just rename it to platexmkrc with no extension. Then just follow the directions given above to have your .tex file typeset using the pdflatexmk engine and make sure that platexmkrc file is in the same folder as that .tex file.

Comment: NOTE: It turns out that the --interpreter option to pythontex down't do what I thought it does. The version of the platexmkrc file given above is a corrected version. It assumes you have anacond3 python in `~/opt/anaconda3/bin`.